# Is it okay to specify exactly why you are sending an HTTP error code?

Tags: api, http, rest, error-handling

If you run an API server then a client sends a bad request, you would usually send him `400 Bad Request` error but is it acceptable if you change the message to a more specific one?

Example:

- `400 Invalid ID`
- `400 Parameter x, y, z is required`
- `400 Minimum length for parameter is x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical place for additional information would be the response body.

Answer (score 2):

There is [precedent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for using your own codes (which can be handy for log file analysis), but there is nothing wrong with putting whatever description you like in the response.